# como puedo hacer que se guarde el return de método numeroDeLinea en el archivorespuesta

Tags: java, archivo, binario

Estoy tratando que la respuesta del método NumeroDeLineas lo pueda guardar en un archivo binario

```
//Numero De Líneas Binario

public int  NumeroDeLineas ( ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{ 
    FileInputStream leer = new FileInputStream(ArchivoObjetivo);
    String numeroDelineas= "";
    while (leer.available() != 0) {                
                char caracterLeido = (char) leer.read();
                numeroDelineas += caracterLeido;
            }
    //Separación por lineas
               String[] separadaLinea = numeroDelineas.split("\n");
               int numlineas = separadaLinea.length;
          leer.close();
               return  numlineas ;
    }
    //Guardar De Lineas Binario
    public static void  GuardarRespuesta  (String nombreArchivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File archivo = new File ("archivorespuesta.txt");
        FileOutputStream escribir = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        
        escribir.write('');
        escribir.write('\n');
        escribir.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: En el método `GuardarRespuesta`, debajo de la línea donde construyes `archivo` agrega `archivo.createNewFile();`. Esta línea crea el archivo si el archivo no existe. Si ya existe no hace nada. Eso evitará que obtengas  `FileNotFoundException`.